# Placeholders Not Instantiated when adding Controls Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, controls, pageload

I have a an ASPX Page with a Placeholder control declared.

In the Codebehind I create a UserControl I have and add it to the Placeholder.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      UserControl uc = new ChartUserControl();
      myForm.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

The UserControl in turn has a Placeholder, but in the Page_Load (for the UserControl) when I do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebControl x = new WebControl();
    userControlPlaceholder.Controls.Add(x);
}
```

It gives me the ubiquitous "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception.

I've tried forcing instantiation by calling a constructor, but that has gotten me into other trouble.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just spent 4 hours on this myself.

The problem is that you're creating the user controls with

```
ChartUserControl chart = new ChartUserControl();
```

but you have to use LoadControl:

```
ChartUserControl chart =
   (ChartUserControl)LoadControl("~/path/to/control/ChartUserControl.ascx");
```

Apparently, LoadControl initializes the user control so that its PlaceHolders (and I would assume, other controls it contains), won't be null when you use them.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you - this has also got me out of a big pile of doo-doo.

Comment: Excellent! I thought I was going to have to rethink my entire approach for this project.

Comment: besides `LoadControl()` are there any other implementations to instantiate a UserControl?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding the control in the Page_Load, Override the CreateChildControls method and add it there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, makes a lot of sense.  Getting exactly the same problem though (I put it after the base.CreateChildControls();).